# How to handle Laravel 5.2 Connection Exception , if Host is incorrect

Tags: laravel-5, connection

I am using dynamic connection in laravel 5.2

```
try{
    $mt4connection = DB::reconnect('mt4db');
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo "test";exit;
    $e->getMessage();
}
it is throwing exception :
 [PDOException]                                                              
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on '52.44.48.105' (4)
```

But not coming in catch block. 
How can i handle this, Please help me.

Comment: Did you try `catch(\Exception $e)` or `use Exception` due to namespace foo?

Comment: Yes @Robert i used both but did not get any help.